# how laravel get the user id from session?

Tags: laravel, session

Ok, now I know that if I use file driver for session, the sessions are going to be stored in `/storage/framework/sessions` , when I echo the `Session::getId()` I get the session Id that is stored in the storage.

when I open that session, it look like something like this:

```
a:7:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"hgG3c6DQ5XHEvwK7925CmfGUK54dhFPIWB2kFCUz";s:3:"url";a:0:{}s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:27:"http://e-learning.local/p2p";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:50:"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d";i:6;s:3:"key";s:8:"smothing";s:22:"PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA";a:0:{}}
```

> This is localhost development so no warry to publish the session

I wounder, there is no user id or user name at all !, how laravel get the auth user from this session !

what is the value needed to be matched in order to know the user ?

e.g `Auth::id()` get the user id from session, but how ! if there is no indicator in the session about the user id or something :\

furthermore, if I have the session id for the user, and I can't use `Auth::id()` to get the user id (due to fact that I'm building another app using another framework inside laravel, but they should have the same users) , can i get the user from the session ?

Comment: apparently, the keys are hashed, and to access user info, you have to decode them. This way, people without access to server can not fetch user info from their session file

Comment: @FatemehMajd nice, how to do the decryption if i have the session id ?

Comment: I do not know the exact way, but I know it has something to do with app_key

Answer (score 0):

In my application i have found user_id listed as value for this dynamic key "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d"

This is what i run to get sessions of all users & identify their session id, along with user id:

```
        foreach (glob(base_path()."/storage/framework/sessions/*") as $filename) {
            foreach (unserialize( file_get_contents($filename) ) as $key => $value) {
                if(substr_count($key, 'login_web') > 0){
                    echo "Session ID: " . basename($filename) . " - User ID: ".$value."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```